# what is difference between ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder vs ITokenAcquisition?

Tags: azure-ad-msal, adal

what is difference between  ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder  vs ITokenAcquisition ?

as per understanding ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder   use for application token.

ITokenAcquisition  for user token ?

Answer (score 0):

Both [ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.confidentialclientapplicationbuilder?view=azure-dotnet) and [ITokenAcquisition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.web.itokenacquisition?view=azure-dotnet) can be used for user and application authentication and token acquiring.

The latter is inherited by classes that encapsulate the former and is intended to be used from web apps and web apis while the former can be used from desktop, mobile (special scenarios) and daemon apps.

Comment: then when to use which option ?

Comment: ITokenAcquisition is the recommended one to be used with 
the Microsoft.Identity.Web package. For additional customization you can use ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder which is part of the Microsoft.Identity.Client package. The former is intended only for web applications and apis while the latter for any kind of application.